# Delete record from Access database vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vb.net-2010

In this project I use Access database which is displayed in DataGridView. I am trying to delete acces row but i my looking for was not successful.

Code to delete record from DataGridView:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

    Dim index As Integer
    index = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(index)


 ZoznamBindingSource.RemoveCurrent().                                                                            
 ‘Dim da As OledbDataAdapter
  ‘Dim ds As dataSet                                                 
   da.Update(ds)
 End Sub
```

The last line of code give me an error: SystemNullReferenceException. I know rhe dataset is problem but i don’t know which code will replace it with.

Any solution?

Comment: How have you bound the data grid view?  BindingSource, direct to table/dataset?  Built DataGridView Rows?

Comment: I used BindingSource

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a `BindingSource` is that it is the one and only point of contact for bound data. You shouldn't have to touch the UI and you shouldn't have to touch the data source.

In your case, you should be calling `RemoveCurrent` on the `BindingSource`. That will flag the underlying `DataRow` as `Deleted` and then, when you call `Update` on your data adapter, the corresponding database record will be deleted.

Comment: I used RemoveCurrent() and when i updated dataadapter i got an error System Null Reference Exception

Comment: @Lasicak, then you did something wrong but you haven't explained what you did or shown us the relevant code so we can't possibly help you with that issue. Take the site tour if you haven't already and spend some time in the Help Center to learn how this site works. Not surprisingly, part of that is providing all the relevant information about the issue you want help with.

Comment: Don't post unformatted code in an answer and expect anything useful to happen. ALL the information relevant to the question should be in the question, formatted appropriately. No one should have to read the comments on the question, never mind on an answer, to understand the question. If it becomes apparent that information you didn't originally provide is relevant, edit the question to provide it.

Comment: sorry, but good to know. Now my question is edited with the problem code.